# How do I retrieve representation metadata for properties in the datastore?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I'm getting a `ClassCastException (java.lang.Double cannot be cast to java.lang.Long)` when retrieving multiple instances of a class in the datastore. The class has many values that are doubles and many that are longs. I'd like to view what is in the datastore and compare with the class properties to see if there is a mismatch. I tried the `representationsOfProperty` method found near the bottom of https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/metadataqueries#Java_Kind_queries, but my queries return `null`.

I have a class defined similar to the following:

```
@PersistenceCapable(identityType = IdentityType.APPLICATION)
public class Container
{
    @PrimaryKey
    @Persistent(valueStrategy = IdGeneratorStrategy.IDENTITY)
    private Long    containerID         = null;

    @Persistent
    private Long    extensionID     = null;

    @Persistent
    private String  homeUrl;

    @Persistent
    private Double containerScore;
}
```

I copied the code from the GAE page linked above. The only change I made was to convert '**key**' to "**key**" since a string is requested and what is shown in the example isn't a character.

```
Collection<String> representationsOfProperty(DatastoreService ds,
        String kind,
        String property) 
{

    // Start with unrestricted non-keys-only property query
    Query q = new Query(Entities.PROPERTY_METADATA_KIND);

    // Limit to specified kind and property
    q.setFilter(new FilterPredicate("__key__",  Query.FilterOperator.EQUAL, Entities.createPropertyKey(kind, property)));

    // Get query result
    PreparedQuery pq = ds.prepare(q);
    Entity propInfo = pq.asSingleEntity();

    if( null == propInfo )
    {
        Collection<String> strs = new ArrayList<String>();
        strs.add( "[ERROR: Invalid Query: " + pq.toString() + "]" );
        return strs;
    }

    // Return collection of property representations
    return (Collection<String>) propInfo.getProperty("property_representation");
}
```

I call that method with the following code:

```
DatastoreService datastore = DatastoreServiceFactory.getDatastoreService();
String prop = "containerID";
Collection<String> reps = representationsOfProperty( datastore, Container.class.toString(), prop );
```

Unfortunately, `propInfo` is always `null`. Any ideas on what I could try? Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: It seems like you might run into issues since you're persisting the data with JDO and retrieving with the Low-level API. See [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/jdo/queries) on how to make queries in JDO.

Comment: I was only doing in my attempt to troubleshoot a separate problem where I could retrieve one class at a time, but not multiple classes in a single query. The code had worked before, but broke after an update. I was hoping to look at metadata and see the storage type of my fields.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just created a sample project to reproduce your issue. JDO is saving the entities in the Datastore, but not naming the primary key property according to the member variables of the `PersistenceCapable` class. Check your datastore viewer and grab a random `Container` entity to see what's happening.

If you need to do metadata queries on the id property in this manner, you should be aware that the ID/Name property is part of the key. [Check this interesting talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tx5gdoNpcZM) to learn more about how the Datastore internals work (it's based on BigTable).

Comment: Thanks. I should have thought of that as I had noticed that before. With my normal JDO queries, I didn't have to mangle the name and have gotten used to using the field name for every query.